# Macro wrongly defined in Makefile of Openwrt package

Tags: c, makefile, c-preprocessor, openwrt

In the openwrt package that I'm working on, I defined a new config flag by adding following bloc to the Config.in file:

```
config VENDOR_PREFIX
    string "Vendor Prefix"
    default "X_Custom_SE_"
```

The flag is well added in the menuconfig:

[image]

I want that the value of this config flag is viewed in my C code as a macro. So I defined a macro CUSTOM_PREFIX  in the Makefile of the package and assigned to it the value of the defined flag with this way:

```
TARGET_CFLAGS += -DCUSTOM_PREFIX=\"$(CONFIG_VENDOR_PREFIX)\"
```

and then I tried to use my macro in my C code by calling it in a structure variable initiation like that:

```
struct parameter_struct param1= {CUSTOM_PREFIX"param1", 4};
```

After that I tried to compile it. But I got this compilation error:

```
/home/user/openwrt//staging_dir/toolchain-mips_mips32_gcc-5.5.0_musl/usr/include -I/home/user/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_mips32_gcc-5.5.0_musl/include/fortify -I/home/user/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_mips32_gcc-5.5.0_musl/include -I/home/user/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_mips32_musl/usr/include -I/home/user/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_mips32_musl/usr/include -I/home/user/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_mips32_musl/usr/include -DCWMP_VERSION=\"3.0.0\" -I../inc/ -I../dm/ -I../dm/dmtree/ -I../dm/dmtree/common -I../dm/dmtree/tr098 -I../dm/dmtree/tr181 -I../dm/dmtree/upnp -Os -pipe -mips32 -mtune=mips32 -fno-caller-saves -DCONFIG_TARGET_iopsys_brcm63xx_mips -g3 -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -fhonour-copts -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=unused-result -msoft-float -iremap/home/user/openwrt/build_dir/target-mips_mips32_musl/icwmp-curl/icwmp-4.0-2018-03-21:icwmp-4.0-2018-03-21 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro -DCUSTOM_PREFIX=X_CUSTOM1_SE_ -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_AADJ -MT ../dm/dmtree/common/libdatamodel_la-deviceinfo.lo -MD -MP -MF ../dm/dmtree/common/.deps/libdatamodel_la-deviceinfo.Tpo -c ../dm/dmtree/common/deviceinfo.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o ../dm/dmtree/common/.libs/libdatamodel_la-deviceinfo.o
                 ^
../dm/dmtree/common/deviceinfo.c: At top level:
<command-line>:0:15: error: 'X_CUSTOM1_SE_' undeclared here (not in a function)
../dm/dmtree/common/deviceinfo.c:28:2: note: in expansion of macro 'CUSTOM_PREFIX'
 {CUSTOM_PREFIX"param1", 4}
```

struct parameter_struct param1= {CUSTOM_PREFIX"param1", 4};
seems like that the c program doesn't accept it as a string.
Is there something wrong in my macro definition?

Comment: Try without `\"` ? Maybe the `CONFIG_VENDOR_PREFIX` is already a string.

Comment: @EugeneSh. no it doesn't work. Same issue

Comment: Well, you can probably work around it by `#define STR(x)    #x` and then `STR(CUSTOM_PREFIX)`. But it won't explain why this is not working.

Comment: @EugeneSh. if I use your suggestion, good, I don't get a compilation error. But I don't get good result in the execution. because in c code the structure initiate will be struct parameter_struct param1= {STR(CUSTOM_PREFIX)"param1", 4}; so I get as string "CUSTOM_PREFIXparam1" but I want it X_CUSTOM1_SE_param1

Answer (score 1):

As I expected and I noted in the my post title the mistake is in the definition of the macro in the Makefile. In Openwrt Makefile the definition of the Macro should be like that:

```
TARGET_CFLAGS += -DCUSTOM_PREFIX=\\\"$(CONFIG_VENDOR_PREFIX)\\\"
```